# Python equivalent of MATLAB's lsqr() with first argument a function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

As per title, I am looking for a Python equivalent of MATLAB's `lsqr()` (possibly in NumPy / SciPy) when the first argument is a function.

Briefly, `lsqr` solves numerically for `x` the following problem:

```
argmin_x || A*x - b ||_2
```

where `x` and `b` are vectors (of potentially different size) and `A` is a linear operator.

I believe that for numerical input the equivalent is `numpy.linalg.lstsq()`.

The function `scipy.optimize.least_squares()` can, in principle, be used for solving the argmin problem, but it seems that it uses a different (and much slower) algorithm internally, which seems unsuited for optimization over relatively large inputs.

I believe that `lsqr()` internally uses `A*x` and `A'*b` and does not require an explicit rappresentation of `A`.

So, is there an equivalent of MATLAB's `lsqr` (with first argument a function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large and sparse inputs (which would be the use case for `lsqr` anyway), the Python / SciPy equivalent of MATLAB's `lsqr` is:

```py
scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()
```

The first argument of this function can be `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator()`, which is a proxy for the linear operator where `A*x` and `A'*b` (`'` is the transpose operator) must be provided as the callable corresponding to `matvec` and `rmatvec` (respectively).

This can ultimately be used to compute `lsqr` where `A` is not known explicitly.

For example:

```py
def Ax(x):
    """Returns A*x"""
    ...

def Atb(b):
    """Returns A'*b"""
    ...

A = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((m, n), matvec=Ax, rmatvec=Atb)
result = scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b)
```

Note that both [MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqr.html) and [Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr) documentations of `lsqr` indicate that `A'*x` (more precisely `A^T x` in the case of Python, but with the same meaning) is computed, but this is not (and cannot be) correct.
If fact they both use `x` as a mute variable (not related to `Ax = b` naming), but they both actually use `b`.

An important difference exists between Python and MATLAB implementations:

- **MATLAB**: a single function is provided and it needs to compute `A*x` or `A'*b` depending on the second argument of `afun` (`afun(x,'notransp')` or `afun(x,'transp')`, respectively).
- **Python**: the two functions are to be provided separately, and the first argument is either `x` or `b`, depending on whether the `A.matvec()` or `A.rmatvec()` (respectively) is called.

(This is based on the very informative answer from @AnderBiguri and `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()` [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsqr.py#L98-L568)).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in python's `lsqr` [A can also be a `LinearOperator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html), which is what you are looking for.

The function itself is  [scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html), and the documentation itself has nice examples on how to use it.

Essentially you just create your 2 functions (let's call them `Ax()` and `Atb()`) and create `A` as:

`A = LinearOperator((m,n), matvec=Ax, rmatvec=Atb)`

where `m,n` is the matrix size.

Comment: This looks like it is going in the right direction, but I am confused a little bit about how to use this exactly. I have to perform a few tests and I will report back on how it works out.

Comment: @norok2 what of this confuses you?

Comment: Mainly the MATLAB documentation https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqr.html : there it is stated that A can be `m`x`n`, but then the function is requested to return `A*x` and `A'*x`, but this is not possible if `A` is non-square, unless with `x` they mean two different things -- this is confusing to me.

Comment: @norok2 are you confused about MATLAB's fucntion or pythons function? First of all, LSQR i snot a method for square matrices, do not use it if your matrices are square. Second, MATLAB requires a function that can be called as  `afun(x,'notransp')` or `afun(x,'transp')`, so it retursn 2 different matrices. Same with python. It is very likely that while programatically speaking you need to return `A'*x`, mathematically speaking its `A'*b`, its not the same `x` as in `A*x`

Comment: Are you sure about that? I would have thought that as well that you would need `A'*b` rather than `A'*x`, but debugging the example from the MATLAB documentation indicates that `A` is actually a square matrix and that `x` is always numerically consistent regardless of whether `'transp'` or `'notransp'` is used. But this of course is compatible with the convergence of the solution, and it is difficult to judge this numerically.

Comment: As far as Python is concerned, I am trying to convert some MATLAB code, but trying to use LinearOperator with `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()` (`numpy.linalg.lstsq()` simply would not work with LinearOperator) seems to give satisfactory results overall. It would be good if you would integrate your answer with this information.

Comment: @norok2 Yes, `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()` is the one written and linked in my answer and documentation.

Comment: @norok2 you previous to last comment misinterprets everything. Yes, I am sure about that. `afun(x,'transp')` returns `A'*b` in a linear system of equations of `Ax=b`. All Krylov subspace algorithms need `A*x` and `A'*b`.  However MATLAB's help tells you `A'*x` because the name of the input variable is `x`.  You can use `lsqr` with square matrices, its just not the best algorithm for square matrices. Also, 2nd line from MATLABs documentation: *The m-by-n coefficient matrix A need not be square*

Comment: I would also think that `A*x` and `A'*b` are required. But then why both MATLAB and the `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()` documentation indicate otherwise (i.e. `A*x` and `A^T*x` in the case of Scipy)? By the way what algorithm would you suggest for square matrices?

Comment: @norok2 you are not reading what i say T.T .  In `A'*x` `x` means "input to the function" not "variable in `Ax=b` equation. You need to return `A'*b` mathematically speaking

Comment: Why are you saying that I do not read? I does not look fair to me. Anyway, I just find that the documentation is very confusing on this point.
I checked in the source code of `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` and this is actually doing `A'*b` as you said and the parameter of the function must quite evidently be `b`. This is clearly in contrast to how MATLAB treats the first argument of `afun` which is always and consistently `x`, at least in the symmetric case. At this point I am not quite sure what MATLAB is doing at this point.

Comment: @norok2 No. In matlab, the input variable to the function is called `x`, it could have been called `mrpotato` for what we care. Sometimes `mrpotato`  is `x` and sometimes `b` from the `Ax=b` equation. MATLAB just did not use the most straightforward variable name here, nothing else. Otherwise, MATLAB is not doing `lsqr` but some random, in-existent and impossible algorithm.

Comment: I like `mrpotato` and this could have been a better choice for the documentation, probably. The point is that there is an important difference between `afun` and `LinearOperator`: (1) in MATLAB, the first argument of the `afun` is actually always `x` so, eventually `b` must be taken from somewhere else; (2) in Python, the first argument of `LinearOperator.matvec` and `LinearOperator.rmatvec` are actually different (for `matvec` is `x` and for `rmatvec` is `b`!). I think this is something worth noting. And besides that, the documentation is confusing in both MATLAB and Python. Amen.

Comment: @norok2 yes, matlab sucks in this case documenting it, but ultimatelly it doesn't matter. The inside python code uses 2 different functions for this, while the MATLAB one uses 1 function with 2 different inputs. This is just a design choice and should have no effect in the task at hand. Again, the first alrgument of MATLAB is `mrpotato`, or `x`. Sometimes, its `x` and sometimes `b`, but this should not matter, as you are calling a function so you can easily call `afun(b,'trans')` from the internal code. This is only a documentation issue.